# Adding warning with sp_add_alert doesn't work with "Greater Than" and SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We upgraded our SQL Server from 2008 R2 to 2014.

I want to add a custom warning.

```
USE [msdb]
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name = N'MAN more than 1000', 
                           @enabled = 1, 
                           @delay_between_responses = 0, 
                           @include_event_description_in = 1, 
                           @performance_condition = N'Replication Dist.|Dist:Delivered     Cmds/sec|MyFancyReplication|>|1000', 
                           @job_id = N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
GO
```

This has worked with SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I want to add this Warning, but all I get is this error (it's translated, because my original is German)

> A performance condition must be formatted as:
>   ‘object_name|counter_name|instance_name|comparator( or < or =)|numeric value'.

Did you recognize the missing `>` in the error message?

Why can't I add my custom warning?

Best Regards

Björn

Comment: The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189531%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) says `>` is allowed. I would suggest filing a bug on Connect.

Comment: I know that the documentation says greater than is allowed. I thing it's a bug in the sql server version... I was able to add this warning in sqlserver 2008r2

Comment: I don't have 2014 installed at the moment. Does `msdb.sys.sp_helptext 'dbo.sp_verify_performance_condition'` shed any light on it? The relevant section in 2012 looks like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/W0rX6.png

Comment: Hey Martin, the relevant section on my sqlserver14 looks exactly the same. I'm really confused about this and I can't imagine, why this is not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after research, I had found the answer. The Problem is the @performance_condition, my example will not work. But if I add a "SQLServer:" at the beginning of the Condition, like this:

```
N'SQLServer:Replication Dist.|Dist:Delivered Cmds/sec|MyFancyReplication|>|1000'
```

This is the Key to add custom warnings to Sql Server 2014. I believe this is a bug with the new SqlServer2k14.

Regards
Björn